# Add a space after 3 characters in excel by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there some function to add a space after every three character in Excel vba?
The name of the column header is "POST"

Comment: Yes, you could use `Mid` rather creatively to achieve this goal.  But [so] isn't a free coding service, rather we're here to help you figure out why your code went wrong or didn't do what you needed it to.  Therefore, in order for us to help you correct your code, you have to have tried already to solve the problem and demonstrate this...  If you show what you have already tried, you'll find it's much more likely that you'll be offered the help you need.

Comment: I have tried with the Find and Replace. Find ??? and replace ??? ??. But it doesnt work.

Comment: In VBA, you can do this pretty easily using the `Range.Find` method to locate your column; and Regular Expressions to do the insertions.  If you don't want a space after the three-character group if that group occurs at the end of the line, that is simple to add to the Regex.  Give it a try and post back if you run into problems.

Comment: You can also do this in Office365/Excel2016 using worksheet formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried? This is one way to go about it - *note*: it's always good to check you understand the code before using it

```
Function AddSpace(rng As Range) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim str As String

    For i = 1 To Len(rng.Value) Step 3
       str = str & " " & Mid(rng.Value, i, 3)
    Next i

    AddSpace = Mid(str, 2)
End Function
```

For your string in cell **A1**, use the formula `=ADDSPACE(A1)` to split the string as required. Example below

[image]

Edit: updated code slightly - thanks Tyeler

Answer (score 2):

Since Callum has already provided you with some code, I'll leave this here for anyone who might come across it in the future. This does the same thing Callum's code does, but instead of referencing a different cell in the function, you just put in the string.

Ex. in cell `A1` you could put `=AddSpace("mystring")` and it would return the value in `A1` as `mys tri ng`. Just an option.

```
Function AddSpace(Strng As String) As String
    Dim t As String, i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(Strng) Step 3
        t = t & " " & Mid$(Strng, i, 3)
    Next i
    AddSpace= Mid$(t, 2)
End Function
```